# GCM application works fine on emulator but crashes on android device

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I have developed an application and implemented GCM(Google Cloud Messaging), it works perfectly fine on the emulator as well as on bluestacks but when I run it on a device it stops unfortunately and I can't get the reason.

```
Manifest file
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androiddemos.NotificationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ResultActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".NotificationActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GcmActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.androiddemos" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" >
    </service>
</application>

<permission
    android:name="com.example.androiddemos.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>
<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.androiddemos.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

LOgcat
`01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.example.androiddemos/com.example.androiddemos.MainActivity}
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskStackBuilder.java:236)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskStackBuilder.java:215)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at com.example.androiddemos.GcmActivity.sendNotification(GcmActivity.java:70)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at com.example.androiddemos.GcmActivity.checkGCM(GcmActivity.java:49)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at com.example.androiddemos.GcmActivity$1.onClick(GcmActivity.java:33)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344): Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.example.androiddemos/com.example.androiddemos.MainActivity}
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:225)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(NavUtils.java:298)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(NavUtils.java:261)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    at android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskStackBuilder.java:229)
01-09 14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344):    ... 15 more`

Comment: Neither do we if you don't provide more details ...

Comment: what details u want, complete code or manifest code

Comment: logcat output and the relevant code.

Comment: Can you show the `GcmActivity.java` and mark line 70 in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is because you do not have MainActivity defined in your manifest based on this logcat line:

```
14:55:27.034: E/AndroidRuntime(25344): Caused by:
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:
ComponentInfo{com.example.androiddemos/com.example.androiddemos.MainActivity} 01-09
```

You have MainActivity referenced as the parentActivityName but not defined in the manifest at all:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ResultActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".NotificationActivity" />
</activity>
```

If you are still using MainActivity you will need to add it to the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity">
</activity>
```